# Не работает gapi после смены версии. Ошибка: Failed to authenticate user

Tags: php, google-api

По данной ссылке   [ссылка](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface)

Осуществлялся переход. Выскакивает ошибка GAPI:

> Failed to authenticate user. Error: "{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }"

Вроде все делал по мануалу, плюс прошерстил кучу статей, что-то ничего не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была вот в чем: в прошлой версии API при создании объекта использовался email, на который зарегистрирована учетная запись Google, что–то типа *user@gmail.com*, в новой же версии нужно использовать сформированный самим сервисом email типа: *11111111-ra6ds8ie6tb9tq2og51s84pjo32tg0tg@developer.gserviceaccount.com*

Answer (score 0):

У меня использовался сервисный аккаунт, но была та же ошибка. Помогла синхронизация сервера с NTP

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication

> Invalid Grant
>
> If you receive an invalid_grant error response when attempting to use
>   a refresh token, the cause of the error may be due to the following
>   reasons:
>
> 1. Your server's clock is not in sync with NTP.
> 2. The refresh token limit has been exceeded. Applications can request multiple refresh tokens to access a single Google Analytics
>      account. For example, this is useful in situations where a user wants
>      to install an application on multiple machines and access the same
>      Google Analytics account. In this case, two refresh tokens are
>      required, one for each installation. When the number of refresh tokens
>      exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. If the application
>      attempts to use an invalidated refresh token, an invalid_grant error
>      response is returned. The limit for each unique pair of OAuth 2.0
>      client and Google Analytics account is 25 refresh tokens (note that
>      this limit is subject to change). If the application continues to
>      request refresh tokens for the same Client/Account pair, once the 26th
>      token is issued, the 1st refresh token that was previously issued will
>      become invalid. The 27th requested refresh token would invalidate the
>      2nd previously issued token and so on.

Перевод:

> Недействительный Grant
>
> Если в случае попытки использования ключа обновления, в ответе вы
>   получаете ошибку invalid_grant, причинами могут быть:
>
> 1. Системное время вашего сервера не синхронизировано с NTP.
> 2. Вы превысили ограничения использования ключа обновления. Приложение может запросить несколько ключей обновления для доступа к одной
>      учётной записи Google Analytics. Например, такой подход полезен, когда
>      пользователь хочет получить доступ к одной учётной записи из
>      приложения установленного на на нескольких машинах. В таком случае
>      необходимы два ключа обновления, по одному для каждой установки. В
>      случае превышения лимита на количество ключей обновления, вы получите
>      в ответе ошибку invalid_grant. Лимит для каждой пары «OAuth 2.0 клиент
>      – учётная запись Google Analytics» составляет 25 ключей (учтите, что
>      это количество может измениться). В случае, если приложение продолжает
>      запрашивать ключи обновления для той же пары клиент/учетная запись,
>      как только будет выдан 26 ключ обновления, первый станет
>      недействительным. Аналогично, 27 ключ сделает недействительным 2 ключ
>      и так далее.

Comment: видел такое решение, у меня время было синхронизированно, поэтому это решение мне не помогло